# How to create folders in google drive without duplicate using c#?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, directory

I am trying to create a folder on my google drive and check if it already exists. I am new to c#, so I wrote a code to create a specific folder in which I can upload my CSV files, but each time my application runs, it creates a duplicate folder with same name and I am now trying to figure out how to stop it.

```
 class GoogleApi
{
    private string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
    private string ApplicationName;
    private string FolderId;
    private string FileName;
    private string FilePath;
    private string ContentType;


    public GoogleApi(string fileName, string filePath)
    {
        ApplicationName = "MantisToDrive";
        ContentType = "text/csv";
        FileName = fileName;
        FilePath = filePath;


    }

    public void Upload()
    {
        UserCredential credential = GetCredentials();
        DriveService service = GetDriveService(credential);
        FolderId = CreateFolderToDrive(service, "MantisData");
        UploadFileToDrive(service, FileName, FilePath, ContentType);

    }

    private DriveService GetDriveService(UserCredential credential)
    {
        return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {

            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,

        });
    }

    //verify User Credentials using client_secret.json file 
    private UserCredential GetCredentials()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath , true)).Result;

        }


            return credential;
    }

    private string UploadFileToDrive(DriveService service, string fileName, string filePath, string contentType)
    {
        var fileMatadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
        fileMatadata.Name = fileName;
        fileMatadata.Parents = new List<string> { FolderId };

        FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;

        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            request = service.Files.Create(fileMatadata, stream, contentType);              
            //service.Files.Delete(fileName).Execute();
            request.Upload();              
        }
        var file = request.ResponseBody;
        return file.Id;
    }

    // creating folder in google drive to store CSV 

    public static string CreateFolderToDrive(DriveService service, string folderName)
    {
        bool exists = Exists(service,folderName);
        if (exists)
            return $"Sorry but the file {folderName} already exists!";

        var file = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
        file.Name = folderName;
        file.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
        var request = service.Files.Create(file);
        request.Fields = "id";
        var result = request.Execute();
        return result.Id;
    }
    private static bool Exists(DriveService service, string name)
    {
        var listRequest = service.Files.List();
        listRequest.PageSize = 100;
        listRequest.Q = $"trashed = false and name contains '{name}' and 'root' in parents";
        listRequest.Fields = "files(name)";
        var files = listRequest.Execute().Files;

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (name == file.Name)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your post is confusing as you say you are not trying to fix it, what is the question. Please read [tour], [ask], and [mcve] to improve your question

Comment: The documentation for `Files.Create` mentions that the name does not need to be unique. You probably want to use `Files.list` to find it, and if it's found, return that id, otherwise to create the folder.

Comment: refer this https://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-upload/

Comment: @BugFinder: did it never came to your mind that it is a simple typo and he wanted to say (obviously) "I am now trying to ..." ?

Comment: @jps of course, but a number of edits later.. it was still there. Its only you who've edited it to correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (this checks whether the folder exists in your root folder. If not, the method will create a folder):

```
    public static string CreateFolder(string folderName)
    {
        bool exists = Exists(folderName);
        if (exists)
            return $"Sorry but the file {folderName} already exists!";

        var file = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
        file.Name = folderName;
        file.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
        var request = service.Files.Create(file);
        request.Fields = "id";
        return request.Execute().Id;
    }
    private static bool Exists(string name)
    {
        var listRequest = service.Files.List();
        listRequest.PageSize = 100;
        listRequest.Q = $"trashed = false and name contains '{name}' and 'root' in parents";
        listRequest.Fields = "files(name)";
        var files = listRequest.Execute().Files;

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (name == file.Name)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

In case somebody comes here from the future and the pastebin link is dead. This is how you can upload a file to your google drive:

```
    public static async Task UploadFileAsync(string fileName)
    {
        var file = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
        file.Name = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
        file.Parents = new List<string> {folderID};

        byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {
            await service.Files.Create(file, stream, "some mime type").UploadAsync();
        }

    }
```

Comment: it worked but now i am getting a error message whenever i try to upload a new file in that folder i provided the full code of my class i will really appriciate if you can look into that

Comment: Error Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Which line gives you that error and in what method? I assume the error states that a variable is null?

Comment: when i enter in method: UploadFileToDrive and when it ececute line request.upload();
it give no erreur or exception in compiler but i get a windows popup messege with  erreur msg: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: i have to leave now as my office hours are finished i will comebact to this thread and hopefully i will get my solution :) have a good day ahead

Comment: Let's continue our chat here [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192701/lonely-programmers)

Comment: i think i dont have enough reputation points to talk in chat if there is other mean to discuss 1 on 1 i am up for it

Comment: Alright, this is how you can upload a file to the google drive https://pastebin.com/478BwAfM Obviously, you can change it to a synchronous task.